# How can I remove the powershell banner in vscode?

Tags: powershell, java, eclipse

Everytime I use the terminal for a code, vscode sents this banner. How can I remove it?

It says:

> Windows PowerShell
> Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.
>
> Install the latest PowerShell for new features and improvements! https://aka.ms/PSWindows

```
PS C:\Users\Acer>  & 'C:\Program Files\Eclipse Adoptium\jdk-17.0.6.10-hotspot\bin\java.exe' '-XX:+ShowCodeDetailsInExceptionMessages' '-cp' 'C:\Users\Acer\AppData\Local\Temp\vscodesws_aafc4\jdt_ws\jdt.ls-java-project\bin' 'Main'
```

Comment: Thought about updating it

Comment: Additional starting point: The link on the linked MS post contains the link to install there too which point to: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/install/installing-powershell-on-windows?view=powershell-7.3#msi

Comment: Just open up [WT settings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/terminal/customize-settings/appearance) and select what you want to happen. The banner is there to tell you about new updates. If you have updates set to automatically happen (say in your profile, etc.), then, sure, no reason to display that. You can also, just set your profile to clear the screen on launch.

Comment: Yeah, what @RohitGupta said… Why not just update it?

Answer (score 1):

As per my comment, the below settings could assist you to deal with your concern. For example in 'Windows Terminal' In your ***Settings.json***, find this

```
"guid": "{61c54bbd-c2c6-5271-96e7-009a87ff44bf}"
```

Depending on your version, the above may be different or not exist. Yet, the point is to adjust as needed. For example, something like:

```
"startingDirectory": ".",
"initialRows": 30,
"initialCols": 120,
"disableMessage": true
```

The path for your 'Windows Terminal' settings.json file may be found in one of the following directories:

```
# Terminal (stable / general release): %LOCALAPPDATA%\Packages\Microsoft.WindowsTerminal_8wekyb3d8bbwe\LocalState\settings.json

# Terminal (preview release): %LOCALAPPDATA%\Packages\Microsoft.WindowsTerminalPreview_8wekyb3d8bbwe\

# LocalState\settings.json
Terminal (unpackaged: Scoop, Chocolately, etc): %LOCALAPPDATA%\Microsoft\Windows Terminal\settings.json
```

***PowerShell console/IS, and VSCode natively provide similar settings.json.*** Just open settings and make whatever changes you choose.

> https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/settings